# Ellipses after excerpt AND "Read More"

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, function

I can't figure out how to have both; 3 dots after the excerpt, combined with the 'read more' link (but not directly after the ellipses). There is a plugin that will do this, but I'd rather avoid using one for something so small.

This is the code I am using right now, so as not to interfere with it.

First, I changed "Read More" to "Continue Reading" using this:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Continue Reading...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

---

Then, I added the following so I could have a horizontal rule separating each entry:

```
add_filter( "the_excerpt", "add_class_to_excerpt" );
    function add_class_to_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
return str_replace('</p>', '</p><hr>', $excerpt);
}
```

---

My "Continue Reading" link is on it's own line, bottom right of the excerpt. I would just like to append '...' after the last word of the excerpt. The closest I have found is having it read like the following:

What I don't want:

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's... Continue Reading...

What I want:

The above, but leaving my Continue Reading on it's own line and floated to the right.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,
Tracy

--------------------SOLVED BY JAY!!!
Thanks Jay, Here are my changes (compared to the first snippet of code I originally added:

```
   function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
return '...<span><a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .      '"> Continue Reading...</a></span>';
 }
 add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: Put the link in a span and float the span to the right.

Comment: Jay! That did it!!! I already had it floated to the right. Check this out... all I did was add 3 dots just after the 'return' and before the link...also added the span tag. Here is the new snippet.... well, can't paste it here... I'll add it to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this filter:

```
function ellipses_excerpt_more( $output ) {
  if ( has_excerpt() && ! is_attachment() ) {
    $output .= '...';
  }
  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'ellipses_excerpt_more', 1, 10 );
```

Comment: Sadly, that made no difference anywhere; they didn't show up anywhere. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Theoretically it only works when you get the excerpt via its getter method which applies the "get_the_excerpt" filter like the "get_the_excerpt()" function.
Also you could try to modify the priority of the filter registration for a higher number then 10 (it is the default), in case of an other plugin override my snippet. (I updated my answer, where you will see the constant 10 ehich is the priority, increase that value i.e.: 90)